# what does reachable/unreachable mean in git?

Tags: git

Little bit confused..

In the [git community manual](http://book.git-scm.com/3_reviewing_history_-_git_log.html), it says

> The git log command can show lists of
>   commits. On its own, it shows all
>   commits reachable from the parent
>   commit; but you can also make more
>   specific requests

```
$ git log v2.5.. # commits since (not reachable from) v2.5
```

I thought git log by itself only shows you the commits made to the current branch, and the commits are sequential - so how can you have one commit made since another, but unreachable from it?

I think I'm either misuderstanding what git log does or what unreachable means or both.. grateful for any help!

Comment: Oh, I think I'm getting it. Since each commit only stores its parent, you can build a list of commits back from any commit, but not forward. Therefore any commit since is also not reachable from.

Comment: Correct. This is how git finds all information. It starts from a given known point (e.g. a branch, which points to a given commit object), and walks its way from there through the references to other objects (e.g. the parent(s) of the commit). This is the same as how it finds the content associated with the commit - it effectively walks down through the directory structure (internally represented as trees) to each file (whose contents are stored as blobs).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

in Git, every commit you make (except for the very first) will have a parent commit. It follows that any given commit (except the first) is a child of one (or possibly more than one) other commit. You can also have several branches of development in Git, that begin or deviate at a particular ancestral commit. Nothing in Git dictates that commits must occur in either a chronological or linear order, and thus the `git log` tool needs to be able to deal with several ways of querying history.

For instance, assume I develop my application and make commits in alphabetical order:

```
---A---B---E---G
    \       \
     C---D   F
```

In this example, I must have made a new branch on commit A and E.

If I were to run `git log <D>` (where `<D>` is the commit's SHA), then the log history would look like this:

```
D---C---A---
```

From that commit, only the parents and their ancestor commits can be 'seen'. Commits B, E, F and G are technically 'unreachable' from commit D, as they share no common connected parent commit.

Comment: Thanks. That makes perfect sense.

Comment: This is a little confusingly written - timestamps have nothing to do with it. And `git log` doesn't really "query history" any way but "ancestral". If you ask it for something chronological, it still walks the commit ancestry chain; it just also examines the metadata and applies your time restriction.

Comment: yes, you're quite right - timestamps have little to do with how git log works. I was attempting to illustrate that, though I may be able to illustrate the point better.

Answer (score 6):

"Y is reachable from X" means object Y is reachable from the [DAG](http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/). Depends on what Y is,  this can means:

- **Y is a commit**:  Y is a parent/ancestor of X.
- **Y is a directory/folder/blob**: Y is a part of (to say) a commit in the parent/ancestor tree of X.

For some doc (e.g. git-fsck), it just say "Y is reachable". This means Y is reachable from some tag/branch  (i.e. Y cannot be garbage collected)

Comment: Tip: as a git newbie, I'm unlikely to know what DAG means. Your whole answer went right over my head.

Comment: @bruce: Directed acyclic graph. Everything in git is built around this. A commit object contains a reference to its parent(s), but not its child(ren). In the same way, a commit knows its tree (essentially directory listing), which knows what blobs (essentially file content) and other trees it contains, and so on, but none of them know their parents. See for example the [git object model](http://book.git-scm.com/1_the_git_object_model.html) in the git community book.

Comment: I have added a link to http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/ (git for computer scientist)