# Delete file from Heroku app

Tags: git, heroku, filesize

I had 2 very large files in my git history for some reason, that I needed to delete because they exceeded git's file size when I tried to push. I've deleted them from my entire git history locally, and re-pushed. However, when I try to push to heroku, it says I am missing work locally, and I need to pull. If I run `git pull heroku master`, it pulls down these 2 huge files again, preventing me from pushing my latest changes to heroku again.

Is it possible to somehow delete these 2 files from my Heroku app on that end? They are just image files.

Answer (score 7):

***Warning:** Make sure you understand what you're doing before force pushing! It's probably fine here, but in general it can be dangerous.*

You may just need to [force push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---no-force-with-lease):

```
git push --force-with-lease heroku master
```

This is because you've rewritten your history locally, and your new `master` isn't [reachable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4111844/354577) from Heroku's `master`. Git tries very hard to protect you from losing work.

Here you're telling Git, "I know I'm about to lose commits X, Y, and Z. They're old commits that I've deliberately rewritten. Please take my word for it."