# does git push unreachable objects to the remote

Tags: git

If I use `git commit --amend` then the previous commit (say commit A) is overwritten, which is not completely unreachable since `git reflog` remembers it.

My questions are:

1. If now I do a `git push`, will the commit A be pushed to the remote?
2. If yes, how about completely unreachable objects (for example, after `git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now` to make the reflog forget the commit A)
3. If no, how to make it be pushed as well

Comment: *Question 1*: Nope. *Question 2*: I wish I understood the question... but my hunch is _no_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Moved from comments:

1. There's no "not completely reachable". Either it's reachable, or unreachable (from the pushed refspec). Reachable commits get pushed. Unreachable don't. (In case of plain `git push`, you are probably using the default configuration option `push.default=upstream`, which pushes the current branch; e.g. if you are on `master`, `git push` would push `master`, and all objects reachable from `master`.) A related term is "dangling object" - an object unreachable from *any* other object.
2. `git reflog expire` deletes unreachable objects. After that, those reflogs are not unreachable, they are non-existent.
3. Make them reachable (e.g. by `branch` or `tag` commands). Alternately, use the `refspec` parameter in your `git push` to explicitly select the object. (Every object is, by definition, reachable from itself.)

Comment: I think I still get a little confused by "reachable". A commit "only reachable from reflog" is not enough to get it pushed; but it is still classified as "reachable". So your item 3 is not enough.

Comment: Don't think of it as an English word. It's a Git word, with precise meaning. See [what does reachable/unreachable mean in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111844/what-does-reachable-unreachable-mean-in-git), and [git glossary on "unreachable object"](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#gitglossary-aiddefunreachableobjectaunreachableobject). Your "object reachable only by reflog" is not reachable.

Comment: Thank you. Only util just now I realize: 1. Before doing `git reflog expire`, commit A is already an "unreachable object" so it will not be pushed. 2. `git reflog expire` makes it **non-existent** instead of **non-reachable**.

Comment: Awesome. I added some more clarifications just in case.

Comment: Worth noting: you're right that *reachable* is being used as a jargon word. However, there are two ways to use it: *object X is reachable* (in general, from something unspecified), or *object X is reachable **from reference Y*** (more specific). An object that is reachable from a reflog entry is, well, reachable from that reflog entry. That will keep the object alive in the *repository*. It won't necessarily be reachable from the *reference*, though.

Comment: When `git push` sends objects, it sends those reachable from the *commit or reference you specify* in your `git push` refspecs, minus any objects the server already has. Meanwhile `git reflog expire` expires reflog entries based on the *reflog entry age*, plus one other criterion that Git phrases in a confusing way:

Comment: A reflog entry, by definition, refers to an object. The reflog itself, by definition, is a log of values for some named reference. Therefore, we can ask: *for reflog entry E, is E's value reachable from the reference's value?* If the answer is "yes" then the expiration is based on the *expire* time, but if the answer is "no" then the expiration is based on the *expire-unreachable* time. So this is using a very specific kind of reachability question: can the reflog object be reached from the reference value?

Comment: Last, there's the garbage collection that `git gc` performs. For `git gc`, the crucial question is: *is this object, which I, the collector, found by painfully enumerating every object in the database, reachable from **any** reference, **any** reflog entry, any index entry, any HEAD in any work-tree, or any other sneaky sort of object reference that Git might invent in the future?* If so, `git gc` must leave the object in the database. There was a bug in Git 2.5 through 2.12 or so where `git gc` would accidentally remove objects referenced only from added work-trees!

Comment: @torek, thanks for you explanation. I think I have fully understood your first and second comments. But I get trouble for the third (which also affects to the fourth). What is the difference between "a reflog entry" and the "reflog itself"? Would you please exemplify it for the case `xxxxxx HEAD@{0} commit: x`?

Comment: (Oops, this was wrong, or old, I re-checked and have replaced the comment.) If you look in `.git/logs/HEAD` for instance, you'll see one line per entry. `HEAD@{0}` is the last line in that file. It contains a hash ID, your name, a time stamp, and a message. `HEAD@{1}` is the 2nd-to-last line, and so on.

Comment: So, by "the reflog" I mean "the entire contents of that file" or even "the entire contents of every file in `.git/logs`". The fact that these are in `.git/logs` is an implementation detail: GIt could move them to a binary database, instead of a series of text files. If the Git guys did that, each "virtual line" in the database would still be one log entry, associated with the reference that created it. There's a proposal to keep reflog entries around when deleting a reference (`git branch -D ...` for instance) so as to be able to undelete the reference later.

Comment: Because Git is implemented on real OSes with real naming restrictions, actually *accepting* this proposal would more or less force Git to stop storing the reflog entries in separate plain-text files. This would also be a good time to fix issues with branch names being sometimes-case-insensitive sometimes-case-sensitive, by moving all *reference* names from separate files in `.git/refs` to a binary database. However, all of these would be pretty disruptive in other ways...